# Sql Server Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a one table tbl1 have five columns, columns is sno, code, height,width,size 
structure is

```
sno. code height width size 
---------------------------
1     s1   3      5    3x5
2     s2   4      6    4x6
3     s3   5      8    NULL
4     s4   8      12   NULL
5     s5   9      11   NULL
```

I want to know if i am updating size for the code s3  size instead of NULL is 5x8 by query 
use this for working

```
UPDATE   tbl1
SET   size = height 
WHERE     (sno = '3')
```

but if i use

```
UPDATE   tbl1
SET   size = height, 'x' width
WHERE     (sno = '3')
```

not working

Comment: What error are you getting ? I think there may be type conversion problem . Can you tell me the error ?

Comment: if your size is represented as 'Height x width' every time i would not bother storing it. Instead use your front end or business layer to do it.

Comment: Or if you do want this in the database, you could do it as a computed column (therefore always correct) rather than having to issue this `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE   tbl1
SET   size = CAST(height AS VARCHAR(5)) + 'x' + CAST(width AS VARCHAR(5))
WHERE     (sno = '3')
```

But I agree with bhupendra patel's comment. Don't bother storing that, it's only a formatting matter which can be dealed with by a higher layer.

Comment: if `height` and `width` are number, you do a cast first, `CAST(height AS VARCHAR(5))` before concatenating it to avoid error. `:)`

Comment: if you are using height and width as int then you need to convert it to verchar first. you can use convert(varchar , height) + 'x' + convert(varchar , width) .

Comment: I was just checking this in a fiddle, completing right now. Thanks for pointing that out :)